# Network interface goes down when resuming VM

Tags: networking, 20.04, suspend, virtualization, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop as a VM with VMWare workstation Pro 16 hypervisor, and a Windows 10 laptop host, using NAT network configuration.

Sometimes, yet not always, when resuming my VM after using the *Suspend Guest* option from VMWare (see the following screenshot) without suspending Ubuntu from the built in power menu, my NIC goes down, and I have to run the commands below to resume my access to my home network and Internet:

```
sudo ip link set dev ens33 up
dhclient
```

Here is the VMWare menu:

[image: menu screenshot]

Is this because after a while Ubuntu enters deep sleep mode?

It confuses me because I can have my machine suspended for days, with my laptop turned off and not always have my NIC go down after resuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out: it seems like when my laptop enters deeper sleep level, my wireless NIC is put to power saver mode, and partly disables itself.

When waking it up and resuming my VM, Ubuntu does not detect quick enough the NIC, and skips the network configuration process.

To solve this, I created a small script with the two commands I use to enable the NIC, and renew my IP address (demonstrated at the question), and created a new keyboard shortcut to it.

I was also thinking about makin this scripts as some sort of a service that runs automatically on system wake up (assuming it won't run if NIC is enabled), yet I'm not sure if suspending a VM from the hypervisor itself also sends the Ubuntu OS to sleep mode as well.
I will try this automated solution as well and update my answer with the results.

Comment: Yes, the commands do help and restore network connection. But I had to use "sudo dhclient" for the 2nd command.

Answer (score 0):

**i fix the error !!!**
go to Virtual Network editor and click on "Restore defaults" buton

This link helpme https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/No-more-network-in-VMs/td-p/2926219